# PHP Smarty replace

Tags: php, smarty

I use PHP Smarty and now I want to use `replace:` on a more correct way.

I want to remove the entire `<div class="news-text"></div>` and its inner content.

How can I achieve that?

My code currently looks like this, but it is nasty because it only hide the content:

```
{$announcement.text|replace:'<div class="news-text"> ':'<div style="display:none;" class="news-text">'}
```

Comment: Why not just `{$announcement.text|replace:'<div class="news-text"> ':''}`? That said, this should probably be handled outside the view, and handled via a proper DOM manipulation.

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks! Well because than the inner conent of the `<div class="news-text">` still is displayed/loaded. And I need a way to remove the entire `<div class="news-text">` with the inner content.

Comment: Then you really need DOM manipulation. http://php.net/dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty cannot do that in a reliable way. You can try to create a custom plugin to manipulate html or better, modifiy the contents of the variable before sending it to Smarty.

Your current solution is also unnecessary and may be prone to errors. You can do it with simple css, no replace required; i.e.:

html:

```
<div class="no_news_text">
{$announcement.text}
</div>
```

css:

```
.no_news_text .news-text{display:none !important;}
```